# Exception Error: chrome://app/content/app1.js - EXPORTED_SYMBOLS is not an array

Tags: xul

"EXPORTED_SYMBOLS is not an array" Exception flagged when tried to use Components.utils.import("chrome://app/content/app1.js");.

I have a XUL application created and from one of the JS File(say app.js) I tried to include the other JS File as shown above.

Both app.js and app1.js are placed in content folder and also in chrome.manifest file following line is added

"content app content/"

In other JS File (app1.js), I have exported symbols like

```
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["Fooinstance"];

var Fooinstance = {
   foo: function() {
   ...
   }
}
```

In app.js,

```
Components.utils.import("chrome://app/content/app1.js"); 
// Error: chrome://app/content/app1.js - EXPORTED_SYMBOLS is not an array 

...
Fooinstance.foo();
```

I am running this XUL app on XULRunner 17.0.1 win32 libraries.

I looked through the code in this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Using

It did not help and if I include it as resource it works however I do not want to include it as part of resource.

Could you someone point out what mistake would be ?

Comment: Everything seems to be correct - sounds like a caching issue. Try running your app with `-purgecaches` command line flag?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. even after running app with -purgecaches still the same issue..

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and I solved it:
1) changing the file extension (.js) by .jsm
2) Adding a first line on your module exporting classes to share. EG:

```
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["Xobject"];

function Xobject(){
}
Xobject.prototype.stop = function() {
    return 'stop';
}
Xobject.prototype.run = function() {
    return 'running';
}
```

3) Calling this way

```
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm' );
Components.utils.import("chrome://myFirstAddOn/content/Xobject.jsm");

var myXobject = new Xobject();
alert(myXobject.run());
```

Hope it help u

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else getting this, another possible reason is a circular dependency. My case was a little different, but I had two JSM files each using Components.utils.import to import each other. Then I got this error in one of them.